# Can't see the prices on the home page after login woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I have added a code for hiding my prices while the customer, not login, it worked well at the beginning but today I found that even user logged in with the account, the prices are not showing, I rewrite the code, then the prices of shop page and single product page are showing, but the HOME page doesn't showing the prices.

```
add_action( 'init', 'mm_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' ); 
function mm_hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() { 
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {       
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );  

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 31, 0 );


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'mm_print_login_to_see', 31 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'mm_print_login_to_see', 11 );
}
}
 
function mm_print_login_to_see() {
echo '<a href="' . site_url( '/registrazione' ) . '">' . __('<p style="color:#f8b62d ; text-align: center">Registra per vedere i prezzi</p>' , 'shoppingcart'). '</a>';
}
```

Comment: I suppose this function is placed in yout ```header.php```. Does your homepage charge the same header? Some templates use ```is_home()``` function to charge another type of header. I recommend you to debbug it to know where your code lose the flux

Comment: ok, i will check it , thank you

Comment: If you find where your code is failing, please share it as an answer